# How to validly parse a non JSON conform stringified data format into an object?

Tags: javascript, string, object, parsing, data-structures

I wanna know if i can convert

```
let serverProps = "{
server-name: New Server,
server-id: 165894343,
server-description: New Server Description,
server-avatar: ./server_avatars/165894343AEAVATAR.jpg,
server-banner: 0
};"
```

To an object please help

Comment: well it is not valid JSON so your choice is to make a custom parser. You can't even use eval since the keys and values are not quoted correctly. And it is a syntax error since no new lines in a string quoted with `"`

Comment: So i do JSON.parse?

Comment: No because it is not valid JSON.

Comment: Where does the string originate? Can you convert it to JSON from the start?

Comment: Probably split into lines, chop of the meaningless first and last line, drop optional commas at the end of each line, split each line by `: ` into a key and a value. Optionally parse numeric-looking values into numbers.

Comment: @GMG ... From both so far provided answers / solutions are there any questions left?

Answer (score 0):

The best solution is to fix whatever is outputting your code into a proper JSON format.

But for this you can split on new lines. Loop over that and split on colon and build your object.

```js
const serverProps = `{
server-name: New Server,
server-id: 165894343,
server-description: New Server Description,
server-avatar: ./server_avatars/165894343AEAVATAR.jpg,
server-banner: 0
};`

const out = serverProps.split(/,?\n/).reduce((o, line) => {
  const [key, value] = line.split(/\s?:\s?/);
  if (value) {
    o[key] = value
  }
  return o;
}, {});
console.log(out);
```

Answer (score 0):

In case of a multiline format like the one given by the OP one could come up with a two folded regex based approach.

- Making use of [`replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) one first [gets rid of the leading and trailing curly braces](https://regex101.com/r/tgYr1x/4), including newlines and the terminating semicolon
- Within a final step one does [`matchAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/matchAll) a regex which uses [named capturing groups](https://javascript.info/regexp-groups#named-groups) and does create the final result by [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) ing the [array of all the captured groups](https://regex101.com/r/tgYr1x/1).

```js
const serverProps = `{
server-name: New Server,
server-id: 165894343,
server-description: New Server Description,
server-avatar: ./server_avatars/165894343AEAVATAR.jpg,
server-banner: 0
};`;

console.log(
  'serverProps ...', serverProps
);
console.log(
  'no braces serverProps ...', serverProps
    .replace((/^{\n|\n}.*$/gm), '')
);
console.log(
  'result ...', Array
    .from(
      serverProps
        // see ... [https://regex101.com/r/tgYr1x/4]
        .replace((/^{\n|\n}.*$/gm), '')
        // see ... [https://regex101.com/r/tgYr1x/1]
        .matchAll(/^\s*(?<key>[^:]+?)\s*:\s*(?<value>.*?),*$/gm)
    )
    .reduce((merger, { groups: { key, value } }) =>
      Object.assign(merger, { [ key ]: value }), {}
    )
);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```